# Jquery Window Scroll Event Not Working - Wordpress / Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I'm building a Wordpress/Bootstrap site, and am trying to use jquery to add a "fixed" class to the navbar when the user scrolls past it:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on('scroll',function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $menu = $('#menu'),
            scrl = $this.scrollTop(),
            menuHeight = $menu.height();

        if( scrl > menuHeight ) {
            $('#menu').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': 0
            });
        } else {
            $('#menu').css({
                'position': 'relative',
            'top': menuHeight
             });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Jquery is working fine - I've tested with a simple alert event, etc. 
However, I've tried for a while and can't get a window scroll event like this to work no matter what I do. I'm not getting any console errors. Can anyone help?

The test site is at http://www.chuckagency.com/wordpress-new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two versions of jQuery loading on the page - 1.11 and 1.4. The older version (1.4) does not have the `.on` API, and is likely the cause of your problems. I would suggest removing version 1.4.

Also, I would suggest binding the scroll event to `window` instead of `document`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm looking at the page source and only see one jquery version loading - where did you find the other one?

Comment: I cannot find it in the source either, so there must be some other script that loads it. I found it through the Elements panel in Google Chromes developer tools. I can't seem to find the script that loads it right now, but perhaps you're in better luck.

Comment: Ah, found it! The script that loads the older version of jQuery seems to be `http://www.e-mailit.com/widget/button/js/button.js`. Try removing it and see if it works better.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working :(  Appreciate your help - I think I'll move on and try another solution, but if you think of something else, let me know!

Answer (score 1):

It actually turned out to be a CSS issue, I had style rule 
`body { height: 100% }` 
Removing this style rule made original event triggering correctly.

Comment: it's somewhere in CSS style, look for style rule of 'body' tag